# T(n) converting to O(n)

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

I am a little confused on the difference between `T(N)` and `O(N)` when dealing with time complexity. I have three algorithms with their respective `T(N)` equations and I have to find the worst case time complexity `O(N)` and I’m not sure how that differs from `T(N)`.

An example would be:

```
T(n) = 150⋅N² + 3⋅N + 11⋅log₂(N)
```

Would the `O()` be just `O(N²)`

Also, should the algorithm with the lower order of complexity always be used? I have a feeling the answer is no but I'm not too sure as to why.

Answer (score 5):

> Would the O() be just O(N²)

Yes.

For large N, the N² term will dominate the runtime, so that the other terms don't matter anymore.

E.g., for N=10, in your example, 150⋅N² is already 15000, while 3⋅N = 30 and 11⋅log₂(N) = 36.5, so the non-N² terms make up only 0.44% of the total number of steps.

For N=100, 150⋅N² = 1500000, 3⋅N = 300, 11⋅log₂(N) = 73.1, so the non-N² terms make up only 0.025% of the total number of steps.

So for higher N, the relevance of lower order terms diminishes.

> Also, should the algorithm with the lower order of complexity always be used?

No. Because Big-O notation describes only the asymptotic behavior as N gets large, and does not include any constant factor overhead, you may often be better off using a less optimal algorithm with a lower overhead.

In your example, if I have an alternate algorithm for the problem you are trying to solve that has runtime T'(N) = 10⋅N³, then for N=10 it will take only 10000 steps, while your example would require 150067 steps. Basically, [for any N ≤ 15](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2810%29N%5E3%20=%20%28150%29N%5E2%20%2b%20%283%29N%20%2b%20%2811%29log_2%28N%29), the T'(N) algorithm would be faster, and for any N > 15, your T(N) algorithm would be faster. So if you know in advance that you are not going to see any N > 15, you are better off by choosing the theoretically less efficient algorithm T'(N).

Of course, in practice there are many other considerations as well, such as:

- Availability of algorithms that you can reuse in libraries, on the web, etc.
- If you implement it yourself: ease of implementation
- Whether or not the algorithm scales to multiple cores or multiple machines easily

Answer (score 2):

T(n) is the function representing the time taken for an input of size n.  Big-oh notation is a classification of that.  Like you said in your example, the big-oh of that example would be n^2.

Regarding your second question, big-oh notation indicates the algorithm you should use as the input size approaches infinity.  Practically speaking, there are cases where you would never get an input large enough to compensate.

For example, if T1(n) = 999999999999*N and T2(n) = 2*N^2, eventually n is large enough for T2 to be greater than T1.  However, for smaller sizes of n, T1 is greater.  You can graph the functions, or even solve a system of equations to find out what size of n will make a difference.

Note: Also keep in mind that big-oh is a *bound* on the complexity, which means that you can have a loose bound which is still correct.

Answer (score 1):

T(n) is just a function. O or big oh is a level of complexity.

T(n) can be f(n) or g(n) for that matter.

I hope that is clear.

Big Oh is a measure of the time or space complexity of an algorithm.

You dont consider the lower order for complexity because for very large values of n, the higher order complexity is >> lower order complexity.